# Combinatorics: Permutation Problem, how to know if a solution is correct or wrong

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question: Find the number of ways of arranging 8 Men and 2 Women in a row such that 2 Women are never together.

For the above question, I thought of 2 ways to proceed

1> Arrange 8 men in 8! ways(_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_) and the remaining 2 Women could be arranged in 9P2 ways (in the gaps "_" )
So the answer was 8!9P2

Moment I solved using the above way I thought of another way of using complement instead.
2>Complement 
A=U-A'

U=10! and
A' is the number of ways 2 women are always together, this could be arranged in 
(WW)MMMMMMMM = 9!*2! ways.

Therefore A= 10! - (9!*2!)

What's the answer to this Question?
Could someone help me figure out how the approaches are correct or wrong? and what is the right method to solve these types of problem, where they give X people and say Y number of people are to be met with a condition?

Comment: your first approach is wrong, after placing the men in $8!$ ways you can place the first woman in $9$ ways and the second in $8$ ways, for a total of $8!\times9\times8$ combinations

Comment: That was a small typing mistake from my part which was edited. But could you tell me how my 2nd method is wrong?

Comment: why do you believe your second approach to be wrong? It gives [the same result as the first one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810!-9!2%29%3D8!9*8) and it seems correct to me

Comment: Well... now this makes me feel smart and stupid at the same time.

Comment: That is a very well-known feeling in mathematics.

Comment: Is "9P2" the binomial coefficient $\binom 9 2$, meaning "combinations of 9 taken by 2"? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: No it will be the number of arrangements/Permutation (9*8) i.e. 9!/(9-2)!